# How to create scrollview pagination with each page contain 4 image from plist/nsdictionary

Tags: ios, pagination, imageview, scrollview

I need to make an app that using a scrollview with pagecontrol to view image gallery, each page contains about 4 image and the image are loaded from plist or nsdictionary for example it will look like "WallpapersHD" in appstore.

the example:

```
 ________      ________                  ________      ________ 
|        |    |        |                |        |    |        |  
|        |    |        |                |        |    |        |
|        |    |        |                |        |    |        |
|        |    |        |                |        |    |        |
|________|    |________|                |________|    |________|
 ________      ________    ==SWIPE==>    ________
|        |    |        |                |        |
|        |    |        |                |        |
|        |    |        |                |        |
|        |    |        |                |        |
|________|    |________|                |________|

        First Pge                             Second Page
```

I really don't know how to start,, how to make the imageview have dependency with theimageurl data on plist file.

As you can see in the first page there is a four imageview but in the second page there is only three imageview it because the data in plist is only seven imageurl..
so I need your help to do paging in ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MGGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) is what you need. There's also an example app with the code

Good luck